# Making a static object method call itself at a set interval

Tags: c#, asp.net

Suppose I have a static object that looks like this:

```
public static class TheStaticObject
{    
   public static void InitializeTheObject()
   {
       // equivalent of javascript setInterval(RunEvery10Minutes, 600000);
   }

   public static void RunEvery10Minutes() {   } 
}
```

In the `Application_Start` method I call `TheObject.InitializeTheObject()` and at that point I want the static object to continuously call a method within it every 10 minutes. In JavaScript I'd use `setInterval` but how would I do this in C#?

Comment: JavaScript is a clientside code and will run as long as the user has a page open. Code running that was started from `Application_Start` will only run until the next time the IIS app pool recycles. If you want a long running action you need to use a external service outside of IIS. What are you trying to perform every 10 minutes, are you expecting it to happen client side or server side?

Comment: You could use a `System.Threading.Timer`, but as @ScottChamberlain says, you'll need a Windows Service, Azure WebJob, or equivalent to run something without IIS interfering.

Comment: Something to the effect of while(true) { ...your code...; Thread.Sleep(60000); }   But you can't really depend upon the thread living for very long if this is an asp.net application.  Even if the user is still on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you do it, but... putting this code in the Application_Start is a bad idea. You should create a separate Windows Service that doesn't run within the IIS AppPool.

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public static class TheStaticObject
{
    private static Timer _timer;

    public static void InitializeTheObject()
    {
        _timer = new Timer
        {
            AutoReset = true,
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds
        };

        _timer.Elapsed += RunEvery10Minutes;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public static void RunEvery10Minutes(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```